# Form looks good in Firefox but a mess in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms

Please see attached images. The second image is from Firefox, which looks great, the first is from Chrome, which is a mess.

Anywhere I have a label and input field, in Chrome it goes messy.

[image]

[image]

Both have exactly the same code.

```
    <tr>
       <td class='sale-label-req'>First Name *</td>
       <td class='sale-label-req'><input type='text' name='Contact0FirstName' value='<?=$_POST['Contact0FirstName']?>'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class='sale-label-req'>Last Name *</td>
       <td class='sale-label-req'><input type='text' name='Contact0LastName' value='<?=$_POST['Contact0LastName']?>'></td>
    </tr>
```

As an example.

Comment: Not related, but you have a typo: `Sumbit Order` !

Comment: If you're floating the input field try adding overflow: auto; or overflow:hidden; to that specific class.

Comment: What are the CSS rules for the TD elements?  (Incidentally, using tables for layout like this is generally frowned upon.)

Comment: Is the width of your firefox window different to chrome's?

Comment: Thank you for the typo. Missed that :)

Comment: The width is the same for Chrome and Firefox. What's the first step I should take?

Comment: Not really related but you're using tables for layout when tables should only be used to display tabular data.

Comment: The form code on here is snapped from an ecommerce platform. I just added the divs in there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually,`<td>` will render horizontally:

```
+--------------+------------+
| First Name*  | [_________]|
+--------------+------------+
```

and this both in Chrome and FF. Since FF is rendering this as

```
+--------------+
| First Name*  |
+--------------+
| [_________]  |
+--------------+
```

this is either *not the same* code or there's an CSS which is handling the table-data tags for FF in a way Chrome doesn't understand - ore vice versa.

Check both original HTML and included CSS, use firebug and developer tools on both browser to see what actually is applied to these elements

Comment: He is using wrong table div structure. http://readiness-plan.com/firetest/form1.php

Comment: So what should I do here?

Comment: _Check both original HTML and included CSS, use firebug and developer tools on both browser to see what actually is applied to these elements_

Comment: optionally, you may post the related full html and css code here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to render two cells (`<td>` elements) of the same row (`<tr>` element) *as if they were on different rows*.  The correct way to do this is to *actually put them in separate rows* (i.e., wrap them in separate `<tr>` elements):

```
<tr>
   <td class='sale-label-req'>First Name *</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class='sale-label-req'><input type='text' name='Contact0FirstName' value='<?=$_POST['Contact0FirstName']?>'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class='sale-label-req'>Last Name *</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class='sale-label-req'><input type='text' name='Contact0LastName' value='<?=$_POST['Contact0LastName']?>'></td>
</tr>
```

Better still, stop using tables for layout and adopt a pure CSS approach instead.

__

A couple of unrelated notes:

- Directly including unsanitized user input (like `$_POST` variables) into your response leaves you vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
- Consider using `<label>` elements to mark up the form control labels and indicate semantically which elements they relate to.  This will aid accessibility and also some browsers will focus the target form control if you click on its label.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the style sheet and give particular spaces for each tags in the html.
Don't give fixed sizes. Manage to do with reletive, absolute, and set the front view one after the other. z-index to show them above or below. Start setting in order. Its little messy in the beginning... Good luck. It might help. If you try to open in other browsers as well It might shock you..